# Vista reboots during loading, tried the usuals, and there is a problem finding the OS

Tags: windows-vista, reboot

OS: Vista 64, Desktop

First thing I tried was to Boot In Safe Mode - I noticed that that it would hang on loading AVG???.sys (some AVG file can't remember), and since AVG was the one that asked me to restart in the first place, I figured something was going on with its drivers. So I created an AVG Repair Disk,  renamed all the AVG/avg.sys files. Didn't work - same thing except now when I boot in Safe Mode it hangs on crcdisk.sys.

Next thing I try is booting from the Vista install disk. When I get to "System Recovery Options" under repair it doesn't show my Operating System. 
[image]

In the above, instead of O`perating System: Micr...` there is No, or Nothing, or Unknown (I don't remember). I have 2 hard drives, both partitioned. Although the OS is on Drive 0 first partition, it isn't "C", so maybe this is why it isn't finding it? I've tried chkdsk /F on every single partition, but they all return with no errors found. So now, I'm not sure what to try next. Is there a away to run Start Repair/Restore and choose the OS drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an advertised issue with AVG's latest update:
http://free.avg.com/us-en/faq.num-4080

Hope this helps.